# iphone 20Mb app limit and images/html

Tags: html, iphone, image, limit, image-size

I'm writing an app with a large number of images, and some html, and hoping to bring it in under the 20Mb limit for 3G download - but I'm nearing it already!

I've considered loading the html by a request, rather than from the app bundle, but a lot of the images are on native pages. I know I can load an image from a file on the phone, but I'm not sure what the limit is for the Documents directory.

What are the recommended solutions for apps with a lot of images/html? And can local html files load images from the web?

Answer (score 0):

I have read many other answers in the past relating to this and the consensus seems to be that the limit for writing to the Documents et al folders will be the remaining device capacity.

I know you are aware of the 20MB limit for download OTA and that the app size limit is 2GB - so I think that can indeed only leave you to allow them to be downloaded on request from the web when the user accesses them.

Also, I do not see any reason why a local file would be unable to load images from the web :)

Hope this helps!